# Cable-to-cable crosstalk (Capacitative Coupling)

Tags: capacitance, coupling, crosstalk

I'm having some difficulty understanding the solution to this question.

> Compute the cable-to-cable crosstalk due to capacitive coupling in a
>   harness between two cable pairs having an average separation distance
>   of 3 mm and a 10 m in a cable tray. The cable diameters are 1 mm and
>   both cables are operating at a 100 ohm impedance level. Assume h = 5
>   mm, source logic = 3.5 V with rise/fall times of 500 ns.

The lecturer showed the following diagram when he was talking about the capacitative coupling, and the equivalent (part of) circuit representation.

[image]

The Capacitive Cross-talk Coupling (CCC) is defined as

CCC(dB) = 20 log (\$V_V/V_C\$)

where \$V_C\$ is the culprit source line voltage and \$V_V\$ is the victim load line voltage.

The solution given is as follows.

> The second corner frequency, \$f_c\$, in the spectrum of a pulse (or
>   pulses) corresponding to rise/fall time of 500 ns is:  \$f_c = 1/πτ\$
>   = 637 kHz
>
> \$C_{CV}\$ = 12 pF/m (read from a graph), and \$[ωC_{CV}l]^{-1} =
> > \text{2 k}Ω\$, thus CCC dB = -26.4 dB
>
> Source logic = 3.5 V = 11 dBV, then
>
> Noise = 11 dB – 26.4 dB = -15.4 dBV = 0.17 V < 0.4 V
>
> Thus, switching OK.

I have several questions.

1) I don't know how to get CCC dB = -26.4 dB. I know I can use the voltage divider on the circuit representation to find \$V_v/V_c\$, which means I need to find \$Z_v\$. But to do that, I need to find \$C_v\$, which is the capacitance per unit length of the victim wire, and I don't know how to get this value.

2) What is "source logic"?

3) Why does noise < 0.4V imply "switching OK", and why "0.4V"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source logic most likely means that your source is some digital logic circuit, (some microcontroller or something) which has standard CMOS voltage level of 3.3V. [Explained here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/logic-levels/33-v-cmos-logic-levels). As you cans see, logical "zero" is represented with any voltage from 0 to 0.8V and there is no danger that your coupled noise (0.4V) induces something that may be considered as logical "one" (which is represented with voltage higher than 2V).

Regarding your -26.4 dB question: look at this: Cv is same as Ccv as the lengths and the medium are the same. Input impedance is 100 Ohm, way smaller than any impedance 1/(omega Cv)=2kOhm . Practically, 100 Ohm in parallel with 1/(omega Cv) will be 100 Ohm. So, if you calculate your voltage divider 100/(2000 + 100) = 0.047 = -26.4 dB!

Comment: Ok, so because \$Z_{V1}, C_V and Z_{V2}\$ are in parallel, the potential difference at each branch across them is the same at \$V_V\$, right? That's why the voltage divider is as you stated, 100/(2000+100), i.e. take \$Z_{V1}/([jwC_{CV}]^{-1} + Z_{V1})\$. But my question is, doesn't this value change if instead of taking \$Z_{V1}\$, I take \$[jwC_{V}]^{-1}\$ instead, which then gives 2000/(2000+2000) = 0.5?

Comment: That's why I thought we needed to consider \$Z_V\$, the combined resistance, for the voltage divider? I thought in parallel, we have \$Z_V = [1/100 + 2000 + 1/100]^{-1} = 0.0005\$, then voltage divider is \$Z_V / (Z_V + [jwC_{CV}]^{-1}) = 2.5 \times 10^{-7}\$? Where did I go wrong in my calculations?

Comment: @RokerRivic Can you explain why you've used the voltage divider 100/(2000+100)? Thank you.